# How to move files in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a cross-platform function in Qt that is equivalent to the MoveFile function in Windows and the mv command in Linux?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sure, [`QDir::rename()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qdir.html#rename) following the old Unix / POSIX tradition of calling this rename.

Which makes sense if you think of a file with its complete path: the underlying inodes *just* get assigned a different path/file label.

Comment: There is also QFile::rename() which may be of use.

Answer (score 9):

You would use [QDir::rename()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#rename) but be beware of the special cases when `rename()` can fail:

> On most file systems, `rename()` fails
>   only if `oldName` does not exist, if
>   `newName` and `oldName` are not on the
>   same partition or if a file with the
>   new name already exists. However,
>   there are also other reasons why
>   `rename()` can fail. For example, on at
>   least one file system `rename()` fails
>   if `newName` points to an open file.

Answer (score 0):

[QUrlOperator::copy()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/3.1/qurloperator.html#copy-2) is an alternative to QDir::rename() that may also work for you.

Comment: It looks good, but appears to be dropped from qt4:

The QUrlOperator class is no longer part of the public Qt API. It has been renamed Q3UrlOperator and moved to Qt3Support.

In Qt 4 applications, you can use classes like QFtp and QHttp directly to perform file-related actions on a remote host.

I'm not sure if I should use it.