# How to change file's location with QT Dialog File

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am beginner to QT and trying to change a file's location with a simple interface. Thanks to tutorials, I have managed to write a code that helps user to select a file, but I couldn't figure out how i can change the selected file's location. My code is below:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString filename=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
        this,
        tr("Open File"),
        "C://",
        "Text File(*.txt)"    
    );    
}
```

Now this code selects the file, how can I know let this file to move for example to C://Users ?
Thank you for help

I couldn't use Qdir:rename, how can use that with my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move files in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916090/how-to-move-files-in-qt)

Comment: yes saw that question but couldnt understand answers:(

Comment: What exactly you don't understand? What kind of answer are you waiting then?

Comment: I didnt understand what I should add to this code to move this file tried this:
 QFile file(filename);
  QFile::copy(filename, "C:\\");

Comment: Have you read the first aswer (sort by votes)? The one that starts with `Sure, QDir::rename()...`.  `QDir::rename()` there is a link to the official Qt documentation. Do you still have questions?

Comment: yes read it, my confussion is the first argument in Qdir::rename() should be this? or filename?

Comment: Gosh. Have you clicked the link in the answer?

Comment: yes of course but i am very newbie, just cant get it also read documentation. tried this bool QDir::rename(this,"C://")

Comment: I tried also this bool QDir::rename(filename,"C://"); just cant figure out