# Ways to execute system commands in qt program without opening console window

Tags: c++, qt

I am running `system()` to move files in `qt`. This leads to blinking of console windows, Is there any way to stop the opening and closing (blinking) of console windows or any alternative ways for `system()` to hide console windows.

```
buffer = QString("move \"%2\\*.ico\" \"%2\\%1\" 2>nul")
                  .arg(images).arg(dir);
qPrintable(buffer);
system(qPrintable(buffer));

buffer = QString("move \"%2\\*.jpg\" \"%2\\%1\" 2>nul")
                  .arg(images).arg(dir);
system(qPrintable(buffer));
buffer = QString("move \"%2\\*.jpeg\" \"%2\\%1\" 2>nul")
                  .arg(images).arg(dir);
system(qPrintable(buffer));
buffer = QString("move \"%2\\*.png\" \"%2\\%1\" 2>nul")
                  .arg(images).arg(dir);
system(qPrintable(buffer));
```

Here %2 is directory and %1 is inputted folder name.

Comment: Why not do it in C++ instead of calling out to a shell?

Comment: You probably wanna have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916090/how-to-move-files-in-qt

Comment: `QProcess` or `fork()` + `exec()`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [`QProcess`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qprocess.html) to run external commands.

Example:

```
QString program = "move";
QStringList args;
args << QString("\"%1\\*.ico\"").arg(dir);
args << QString("\"%1\\%2\"").arg(dir).arg(images);
QProcess::execute(program, args);
```

Comment: Can I use ' QProcess::execute(buffer); ' instead of ' QProcess::execute(program, args); '

Comment: @JobinJose, I don't think you can. The entire string in `buffer` is not a program.

Comment: Your code's 3rd and 4th line can be constructed in one line right, like          ' args << QString("\"%1\\*.ico\" \"%1\\%2\"").arg(dir).arg(images); '

Comment: @JobinJose, I don't think that will work though. You need two arguments in `args`. You may use `args << QString("\"%1\\*.ico\"").arg(dir) << QString("\"%1\\%2\"").arg(dir).arg(images);` to make it a one-liner.

Comment: @JobinJose, if `dir` and `images` don't have spaces in then, it should work. From the documentation: *Starts the program program in a new process. program is a single string of text containing both the program name and its arguments. The arguments are separated by one or more spaces.*